# If variable can't have spaces?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I am making an experimental program in batch for a simple chatting interface. In this one, I made a function where if there is the word r placed in chat, it ignores it and just redisplays the text file again. It works fine if I put r and it just refreshes, and if I put one word it works fine, but if I put a word and a space and another word, it breaks and shows the following error:

```
Chat(Put r for refresh):hey hi
hi was unexpected at this time.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Code:

```
@echo off
cls
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Chat
for /f "delims=" %%A in (chat.txt) do (
    set %%A
)
echo %chatt%
echo %chatp%
echo %chatn%
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Chat\Servers\%chatt%
:1
cls
type %chatn%.chat
set /p in=Chat(Put r for refresh):
if %in% == r goto 1
echo %chatp%: %in%>>%chatn%.chat
goto 1
```

Comment: `if "%in%" == "r" goto 1` Use quotes to delimit a string that may contain separators.

Comment: The common solution is to enclose both term in quotes and lose extra spaces. `if "%in%"=="r" goto <don't use numbers>`

Comment: Note using quotes also prevents errors when your variable is blank. If %IN% is blank it resolves to - `if ==r` which is a syntax error. Using quotes it resolves to `if ""=="r"` which resolves to false.

Comment: NB your question from last year you were advised *If you read the help file for the SET command you will notice that there is no space between the variable name and the assignment operator. The usage and examples all clearly show that*

Comment: @ACatInLove: Why "lose extra spaces"? Extra spaces makes the comparison clearer and easier to read (like in Magoo's comment) and it is a good practice when the user change the `==` by the three-letter `equ` comparison operator...

Comment: Because batch is designed to not have spaces. There were no quotes originally. Go with the  flow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to deal with spaces in a string variables contents is to wrap it in quotes. This is the case here. When you use the variables contents with `%in%` the contents are inserted verbatim, so the suspect line would look like this:

```
if hey hi == r goto 1
```

It starts off okay `if hey` but then instead of seeing a comparison operator like `==` it sees `hi` and chokes. So wrap it all in quotes:

```
if "%in%" == "r" goto 1
```

That way it will be interpreted like

```
if "hey hi" == "r" goto 1
```

and the bat engine will know that "hey hi" should be treated as one entity.